# WPF Column Chart Styling: Remove the gradient effect, set the color of the hash marks on y axis (the minor grid lines)

Tags: wpf

I have a WPF ColumnSeries chart, which looks not that perfect. I would like to know how to improve it in three different ways

1. Remove the gradient effect. I passed a solid color as ItemColor, say Green, but I got a gradient color. Is there a way to remove the effect. I know the gradient color sounds like a genius idea and looks nice. But in the small thing I am working on, this is not a good idea.In the following pics, the first one is what i have right now and the second is what I want. The gray is a gradient color (see the column in red circle)
2. To show the hash marks on y axis on the right side of the y axis (the minor grid lines). It is currently stay on the left side and it's black. I would like to know how to show the lines on the right side of the axis and if I can set the color of the lines that would be so great.(please see the pictures attached the ones in blue circle)

(**I've found answer to this actually** http://msmvps.com/blogs/deborahk/archive/2011/03/05/silverlight-charting-formatting-the-tick-marks.aspx)

3. Remove the white border of the column. I've checked it Snoop. However, I still have no idea which layer the border lies. (please see the picture attached the one in black circle)

Please please read the small piece of code below to see what i have now.

```
  <charting:ColumnSeries DependentValuePath="ItemValue" IndependentValuePath="ItemName" ItemsSource="{Binding}">
        <charting:ColumnSeries.DataPointStyle>
            <Style TargetType="charting:ColumnDataPoint">
                <Setter Property="Background" Value="{Binding ItemColor}"/>
                <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Transparent"/>
            </Style>
        </charting:ColumnSeries.DataPointStyle>
    </charting:ColumnSeries>
    <charting:Chart.Axes>
        <charting:LinearAxis Orientation="Y" ShowGridLines="True"/>
        <charting:CategoryAxis Orientation="X" ShowGridLines="False"/>
    </charting:Chart.Axes>
```

For the ItemColor, the behind code is:

```
ItemColor = new System.Windows.Media.SolidColorBrush((System.Windows.Media.Color)System.Windows.Media.ColorConverter.ConvertFromString("Gray"));
```

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 1):

I know this is kinda old and already answered, but I found this post while trying to figure out the same thing as Jan asked about in question 1, and I've subsequently stumbled upon a somewhat less involved way to remove the gradient inside the bars. So I figured I'd share for posterity.

The trick I hit upon is to ignore the bar Background color, and set the ColumnSeries color by setting its *BorderBrush* color, then set the BorderThickness to something ridiculously large (like 100).  If that value is large enough (compared to the likely data set), then the border will completely cover the bar's innards, and the gradiented fill won't be visible.  If it's too large, it doesn't overflow or or appear to cause any odd behavior, so going "too big" makes sense here.  (Though if somebody sees a potential for that to cause an issue, I'd sure like to know about it!)

Here's the XAML:

```
<chartingToolkit:ColumnSeries.DataPointStyle>
    <Style TargetType="chartingToolkit:ColumnDataPoint">
        <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Blue"/>
        <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="100"/>
        <Setter Property="DependentValueStringFormat" Value="{}{0:C0}"/>
    </Style>
</chartingToolkit:ColumnSeries.DataPointStyle>
```

And here's what it looks like:

[image: Chart with non-gradient bars]

Plainly, it's not perfect, you give up having an actual border around the columns, but if that will work for your purposes, it's a lot simpler than re-templating the chart and allows you to more easily control things like the value formatting (I needed currency formatting there, as you can see from the code).

Hopefully that will be of some use or interest to someone.

Answer (score 0):

according to your question 1:
it is WPF default style. Like button or other controls, there is a white border on it. If you want to remove it. Just like button, you can use an empty style to replace windows build-in/default style
the code is like `{<Button BorderThickness="0"  Style="{StaticResource {x:Static ToolBar.ButtonStyleKey` After apply above line, you can remove the whole style on button. I think it is the same for chart.

Question 2:
the black short line is major tick mark style, you could make your own major tick mark style to control the color, length, position and thickness of the tick mark. for more detail please refer:

```
{
                    <charting1:DateTimeAxis.MajorTickMarkStyle>  
                        <Style TargetType="Line">  
                            <Setter Property="Stroke"  Value="Blue" />  
                            <Setter Property="StrokeThickness"  Value="2" />  
                            <Setter Property="Y1"   Value="0" />  
                            <Setter Property="Y2"  Value="10" />  
                        </Style>  
                    </charting1:DateTimeAxis.MajorTickMarkStyle> 
}
```

Question 3:`enter code here`
it is the same with question 1. Please google it and replace the default style. However, after that, you may have to make your own style, that will be quite a lot of work to do.

good luck on your coding

Comment: For the second question, I've googled that and noticed I should declare xmlns:toolkit= 
  "http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation/toolkit" or charting1 as your case and charting as my case. However, the charting is already defined.