# WPF Charts remove gradient fill

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I'm currently working on a simple c# WPF program that has to show a column chart. However the basic column charts of the System.Windows.Controls.DataVisualization.Charting namespace come with a gradient column fill color and I don't want that in program.

Is there any way, either in xaml or in c# code to set the fill brush of the columns to a SolidBrush?
The ColumnSeries are added programmatically while the program is running so I have no access to them in the xaml. I'm still pretty new to WPF and xaml so I don't really know where to start looking for an answer

Here's my code 'til now, it's pretty basic though, there is not really much to see:

MainWindow.xaml.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Controls.DataVisualization.Charting;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
using System.Windows.Navigation;
using System.Windows.Shapes;

namespace WpfApplication1
{
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            ColumnSeries lC = new ColumnSeries();
            List<KeyValuePair<string, int>> valueList1 = new List<KeyValuePair<string, int>>();
            valueList1.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, int>("Developer", 60));
            valueList1.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, int>("Misc", 20));
            valueList1.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, int>("Tester", 50));
            valueList1.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, int>("QA", 30));
            valueList1.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, int>("Project Manager", 40));

            lC.DependentValuePath = "Value";
            lC.IndependentValuePath = "Key";
            lC.ItemsSource = valueList1;

            chart.Series.Add(lC);
        }
    }
}
```

MainWindow.xaml

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:chartingToolkit="clr-namespace:System.Windows.Controls.DataVisualization.Charting;assembly=System.Windows.Controls.DataVisualization.Toolkit"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Grid x:Name="grid">
        <chartingToolkit:Chart x:Name="chart">

        </chartingToolkit:Chart>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

I've found this post: [WPF Column Chart Styling: Remove the gradient effect, set the color of the hash marks on y axis (the minor grid lines)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20957132/wpf-column-chart-styling-remove-the-gradient-effect-set-the-color-of-the-hash) here. The poster's first problem is pretty much the same as mine. The first answers tells him to increase the border size to fill the column, but in my program I still need the column borders so that's not really what I want and that's the only answer so it looks like this is a pretty tough Problem. I would really appreciate your help. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To change the appearance you want to change the Template in the ColumnSeries.DataPointStyle. To do this from code behind would feel very unnatural, so I changed your code just to be able to
define the Style in XAML.

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:chartingToolkit="clr-namespace:System.Windows.Controls.DataVisualization.Charting;assembly=System.Windows.Controls.DataVisualization.Toolkit"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApplication1"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Window.DataContext>
        <local:MainWindowViewModel />
    </Window.DataContext>
    <Grid x:Name="grid">
        <Grid.Resources>
            <!--Set ColumnColor-->
            <Brush x:Key="MyColumnColor">Red</Brush>
            <!--Style override-->
            <Style x:Key="MyColumnDataPointStyle"
                   TargetType="{x:Type chartingToolkit:ColumnDataPoint}">
                <Setter Property="Background"
                    Value="{StaticResource MyColumnColor}" />
                <Setter Property="BorderBrush"
                    Value="Black" />
                <Setter Property="BorderThickness"
                    Value="1" />
                <Setter Property="IsTabStop"
                    Value="False" />
                <Setter Property="Template">
                    <Setter.Value>
                        <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type chartingToolkit:ColumnDataPoint}">
                            <Border x:Name="Root"
                                  BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}"
                                  BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}">
                                <Border.ToolTip>
                                    <ContentControl Content="{TemplateBinding FormattedDependentValue}" />
                                </Border.ToolTip>
                                <Grid Background="{TemplateBinding Background}">
                                    <!--Change Border appearance-->
                                    <Border BorderBrush="#CCFFFFFF"
                                        BorderThickness="1">
                                        <Border BorderBrush="#77FFFFFF"
                                        BorderThickness="1" />
                                    </Border>
                                </Grid>
                            </Border>
                        </ControlTemplate>
                    </Setter.Value>
                </Setter>
            </Style>
        </Grid.Resources>
        <chartingToolkit:Chart>
            <chartingToolkit:ColumnSeries ItemsSource="{Binding ValueList}"
                                          DependentValuePath = "Value"
                                          IndependentValuePath = "Key"
                                          DataPointStyle="{StaticResource MyColumnDataPointStyle}">
            </chartingToolkit:ColumnSeries>
        </chartingToolkit:Chart>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

MainWindow.xaml.cs

```
using System.Windows;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Windows.Controls.DataVisualization.Charting;

namespace WpfApplication1
{
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
    }

    public class MainWindowViewModel
    {
        private List<KeyValuePair<string, int>> valueList = new List<KeyValuePair<string, int>>()
        {
            (new KeyValuePair<string, int>("Developer", 60)),
            (new KeyValuePair<string, int>("Misc", 20)),
            (new KeyValuePair<string, int>("Tester", 50)),
            (new KeyValuePair<string, int>("QA", 30)),
            (new KeyValuePair<string, int>("Project Manager", 40))
        };

        public List<KeyValuePair<string, int>> ValueList
        {
            get { return valueList; }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Please learn how to style WPF Controls, the easiest way is to use Expression Blend. Look [here for an example how to style](http://mitchelsellers.com/blogs/2011/04/20/wpf-chart-styling-explained.aspx) Charting Control

Comment: Thanks for the link, was exactly what I needed. Have been looking for a good example of chart styling for ages but didn't find much...